# Can you add an After Validation javascript callback for Contact Form 7?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

After the form is submitted if the user failed to enter the required fields I want to add additional javascript goodies, but can't figure out where to add my own custom callback after the form has been validated/posted.

Is this possible without hacking the module?

Thanks,
Greg

Comment: for anybody searching: [go here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27799147/600121)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This plugin seems to use JavaScript validation, so you could add your own custom JavaScript validation by hooking into the submit event (for example). Since this is JavaScript, you won't be *hacking the module*.

I suggest using Firebug, or some other DOM inspector, to determine the best place to bind your events.

Also, check out the [plugin docs](http://contactform7.com/docs/). There is also a forum which may provide more specific help.

Comment: We ended up doing something along those lines: $('.wpcf7-response-output').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function() { ... }); Though this isn't perfect. It does work ;)

Comment: Awesome. Glad you figured it out. Thanks for posting what you used. Welcome to StackOverflow.