# How to add additional settings on error in Contact form 7?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I already know the function 'on_sent_ok' to add jQuery actions when the form is submitted with success.
However I want to display a modal window alerting the user when there are submitting erros. There's some function like the one above, but to be called on errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 3.3 new jQuery custom event triggers were introduced:

> New: Introduce 5 new jQuery custom event triggers (invalid.wpcf7, spam.wpcf7, mailsent.wpcf7, mailfailed.wpcf7, submit.wpcf7).

See: http://contactform7.com/2012/09/24/contact-form-7-33/#more-2598

You can use `invalid.wpcf7` like the example below:

```
$(".wpcf7").on('invalid.wpcf7',function(e){
  // Launch your modal window here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Contact form 7 doesn't provide actions when submitted form contains errors.
But Contact form 7 adds some specific classes on the HTML code.
So with Jquery you can check if these classes exist or not and add some actions.