# jQuery - change elements class in dependence of other elements

Tags: jquery

I have an Ajax-Loader (".ajax-loader") that is only visible if my (contact 7) form checks the form for errors. In this moment i want to remove the class="submit-active" from the submit button:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.wpcf7-form .wpcf7-submit').addClass("submit-active");

    $(".wpcf7-submit").click(function() {
        if ($('.wpcf7-form .ajax-loader').css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
            $('.wpcf7-form .wpcf7-submit').removeClass("submit-active");
        }
    });
});
```

This works. The only problem now is: How di I add the class "submit-active" to the submit button again after ".ajax-loader" is hidden again?

Comment: how/when is the `ajax-loader` hidden? Is there an event?

Comment: I found nothing about an event.

Comment: When are you removing this class? You left out the part of your code that would hide the `ajax-loader` and put back the `submit-active` class

Comment: When I click on the button I remove the class "submit-active". Then the form checks the fields. After that I want to add the class "submit-active" again. The more I think about it the more I think this is not possible because I need some kind of event that the script does.

Comment: set a flag against submit

Comment: How does the form check? Is there a function? an ajax call?

Comment: Just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27798264/contact-form-7-ajax-callback. Think I have to try with theese.