# jQuery "submit" is not working when sending a Ninja Forms Form

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms, ninja

I had to change the plugin from contact form 7 to ninja forms. I used a jquery to do some dome manipulation after the contact 7 form was submited. This script is not working on Ninja Forms:

```
jQuery( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    jQuery(".custom-loader").addClass("active");
    jQuery("#content").fadeOut("1000");
    jQuery("#image").fadeOut("1000");
});
```

I get no error. The script is just not executed when i submit a Ninja Forms - Form. Why is that?

Comment: Most likely because the page is unloaded when a `submit` event fires, so you don't see the change being made. Unless the form is sent through AJAX, this isn't going to work as you expect.

Comment: @peesen87 - please provide the html

Comment: May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27798264/contact-form-7-ajax-callback) link will help

Comment: The form is sent though ajax, thats default in ninja forms.